# Can't access object variables in PHP from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a request to the Facebook Graph API that returns a post from a facebook account.

I am simply trying to access the **data** instance of the object returned in PHP but everything I have tried returns **NULL**.

**Sample response**

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": " 111111111111111111100000",
         "message": "Coming soon #PERFECTFIT 05.07.17 \nRegister to be one of the first to find out what it is here ⬇️\nhttp://www.bathrugby.com/the-club/supporters/perfect-fit-register/",
         "created_time": "2017-06-26T17:39:20+0000",
         "link": "http://www.bathrugby.com/the-club/supporters/perfect-fit-register/",
         "full_picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2147-6/19284954_1592534984092755_4946207882807869440_n.jpg?oh=56cc96435f423cec31962966b6f689c2&oe=59DB08B6"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get at the array of objects data provides so I can MVC the data returned in a larger response.

This doesn't currently work:

```
$response->data; // returns null
$response[0]->data; // returns null
$response->data[0]; // returns null
```

Feel I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($response);` after you have decoded it. (if it needs decoding). This way you will see how your data is structured and understand how to access it.

Comment: That is from the `var_dump`. It shouldn't need decoding as surely the key `data` is accessible in the current data structure?

Comment: Please do as advised and var_dump the response. What you have above is not var dumped, it's just a json representation that you think you have and obviously you don't ;)

Comment: _“That is from the var_dump”_ – and that is a simple _string_ value, not any kind of complex data structure. It’s JSON - you have to _decode_ that first.

Answer (score 0):

first decode it with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) then trying to access the data object

```
$res = json_decode($response);    
print_r($res->data);
print_r($res->data[0]->id);
print_r($res->data[0]->message);
```

[code](https://eval.in/822968)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use first json decode function so you can get the data from the json response.

```
$response = '{
  "data": [
  {
     "id": "143384725674462_1592535354092718",
     "message": "Coming soon #PERFECTFIT 05.07.17 \nRegister to be one of the first to find out what it is here ⬇️\nhttp://www.bathrugby.com/the-club/supporters/perfect-fit-register/",
     "created_time": "2017-06-26T17:39:20+0000",
     "link": "http://www.bathrugby.com/the-club/supporters/perfect-fit-register/",
     "full_picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2147-6/19284954_1592534984092755_4946207882807869440_n.jpg?oh=56cc96435f423cec31962966b6f689c2&oe=59DB08B6"
  }
 ]
 }';

$response = json_decode($response);

print_r($response->data[0]->id); 
print_r($response->data[0]->message);
```